# Google Classroom API: Courses list returning unavailable classes

Tags: google-classroom

I am trying to fetch a list of classes which the current user has access to, and I am getting classes returned which the user cannot access.

Using the ruby client I can call

```rb
service.list_courses(course_states: "ACTIVE")
# I have 7 courses returned
```

OR

```rb
service.list_courses(course_states: "ACTIVE", teacher_id: "me")
# I have 3 courses returned (just mine)
```

The issue is that in the first call there are 4 courses returned *which the current user cannot see/access*. This seems like it *shouldn't be happening* as [the docs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) say `Returns a list of courses that the requesting user is permitted to view, restricted to those that match the request.`

Is this a *bug* which I should report [in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191645%2B%20type:bug) or am I misunderstanding what results can be returned in the courses list?

My use case is that I want to create a `course work` item in a course, but I only want to do this for courses that the teacher can access. I thought that the `list courses` should return exactly that list, but, it doesn't seem to (unless I specify `teacher_id: "me"`, but then I'm worried I'll miss courses which the teacher is collaborating on (if that's even possible))

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

### Edited to add

Thanks to @ziganotschka for the API details. After further testing, calling `service.list_courses(course_states: "ACTIVE", teacher_id: "me")` will return courses that the requesting user has created *or* courses that the requesting user is  collaborating on. This wasn't obvious to me as the [course object](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#Course) has an `owner_id` field which is a single user, so, I thought the `teacher_id` might be referencing that.

The issue I had been running into was that I was logged in as the `super admin` which according to the answer below *allows me to see all the courses*. However, I wasn't actually able to access the weblink of any of those courses which is what was confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The behavior of the API is following:

- `service.list_courses(course_states: "ACTIVE")` returns for anyone all the courses in which he/she is participating - be it as teacher or student.
- If an admin calls `service.list_courses(course_states: "ACTIVE")` he can see all the classes of the domain - this is intended behavior.
- service.list_courses(course_states: "ACTIVE", teacher_id: "me") will return only the classes owned by `me`.

Comment: Firstly - thank you very much for the reply!  Secondly _where can I find this documentation_ ? (especially the admin behavior information as that was, I think, what I was running into).  I just created a second test teacher account, made the first account a collaborator and tested that the `course_states: "ACTIVE", teacher_id: "me"` returned the results. It _did_. That makes me feel like the docs should define what "owned" means, as [the course object](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#Course) has a single `ownerId` field which is the creator.

Comment: It is not complete, but some information about the permissions of teachers, students and admins can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users).